# How to get relations filtering by way member attributes with Overpass API?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I need to use Overpass API to get route relations with abandoned railways, that's to say relations with tag route=railway whose way members have tag railway=abandoned.

I tried the following request:

```
[out:json][timeout:90];
rel["route"="railway"]({{bbox}});
way(r);
way._["railway"="abandoned"];
out geom;
```

but it returns only ways with railway=abandoned, not the relation.

For example, there is a case here : https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1ild